# Reading a CSV file in opencv java

Tags: opencv

Good day everyone!

At the moment, what I am trying to do is test the features matching algorithm. I would like to compare the features of an image to a set of 5 other images. As some tutorials said, I could construct a CSV file with the link of training set.

However, in opencv java, I do not find the ported command read_csv.

Do you have any suggestions for my case, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/mldata.html#cvmldata-read-csv) says:

> read_cvs Reads the data set from a .csv-like filename file and stores all read
>   values in a matrix.

Seems like there is no such class in Java port, but 
you can read the csv in Java into an array and then create a new matrix ([docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat)):

```
new Mat(h, w, type);
```

and then call put() to add values into this matrix.